# Are there a set of "universal" error/exception codes?

Tags: standards, error-code

I'm a bit of a polyglot when it comes to programming languages, and most of the languages I use have Error/Exception handling of some sort.

In most languages there's a default implementation of error ID's with their associated messages, but I've never found a list of production codes to base my own error codes off of.

Does such a thing exist?

If not would it be useful, or just noise that most programmers ignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is [POSIX error constants](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) (though their numeric values are not standardized.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - no, it doesn't exist. Every OS, platform and piece of software pretty much has its own error IDs. These are not synchronized or based on any standard set.

I would say that apart from the common errors, this would indeed just be noise, and even with the common one, one one need to standardize them and ensure they are used universally.